# Object of type 'NoneType' has no len() error

Tags: python

What I want is to count the occurrence of a specific word on goole first page result site, and then once again count for another word - if this word appears more than 2 times, then I will change the occurrence of the first word to 0. But I get this error:

File "D:\HQ_Bot-master\answer_bot.py", line 307, in 
    get_points_live()

File "D:\HQ_Bot-master\answer_bot.py", line 293, in get_points_live
    points,maxo = google_wiki(simq, options, neg)

File "D:\HQ_Bot-master\answer_bot.py", line 242, in google_wiki
    count2 = len(words2)

TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Here is my code:

```
import string
import requests 
import json
import urllib.request as urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from google import google
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
import argparse
import cv2
import os
import pyscreenshot as Imagegrab
import sys
import wx
from halo import Halo

def google_wiki(sim_ques, options, neg):
        spinner = Halo(text='Googling and searching Wikipedia', spinner='dots2')
        spinner.start()
        num_pages = 1
        points = list()
        content = ""
        maxo=""
        maxp=-sys.maxsize
        i = 0
        temp = 0
        ques = ""
        translator = str.maketrans(string.punctuation, ' '*len(string.punctuation))
        sim_ques22 = sim_ques.translate(translator)
        while i < 3:
                o = options[i]
                if i <= 1:
                        x = options[i+1]
                else:

                        x = options[i-1]

                o = o.lower()
                x = x.lower()

                ques += sim_ques22 + ' ' + o + ' wiki'
                print(ques)
                page = requests.get("http://www.google.com/search?q="+ques)
                soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,"lxml")
                words = soup.find(text=lambda text: text and o in text)
                if(type(words)is not None):
                    count = len(words)


                words2 = soup.find(text=lambda text: text and x in text)
                if(type(words)is not None):
                        count2 = len(words2)

                if count2 >= 2:
                        temp = 0
                else:
                        temp = count

                if neg:
                        temp*=-1
                points.append(temp)     
                if temp>maxp:
                        maxp=temp
                        maxo=o
                ques = ""        
                i += 1


        spinner.succeed()
        spinner.stop()
        return points,maxo
```

Comment: Since this question is about python I have removed tag "java"

Comment: `words2` is `None`. That's literally what the error says. I don't work with BeautifulSoup, but it's possible that it's traversible only once? If yes, find a way to rewind it to the beginning or just get both find results in one list and later split it into 2.

Comment: could you post complete code?

Comment: Only value of x will be available when i is less than or equal to one and at the end you  increment i , so loop never exits and x never get a value , hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple ternary statement:

```py
count = len(words) if words else 0
```

which is the same as this

```py
if words: # This checks if it is truthy (which None is not)
    count = len(words)
else:
    count = 0
```

If you want, you can swap the conditional for `if words is None`.

EDIT: I used a ternary expression as you use the variable later on. Otherwise, you'll end up with a `NameError`.

Answer (score 0):

just use try and except if at all you want to continue without the error or catch the error and print if required

```
try:
        // your code where you got the error 
except:
       pass
       // or print the error caught if you want
```